# Canon Pixma MG 2522 not printing

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Someone gave me this computer with UBUNTU 20.04 operating system. I'm used to just plugging in the USB from the printer and being ready to print. This computer recognizes the printer and the computer will say its printing and print complete but nothing is printed. There is no download on Canon's website for this printer. I don't know what to do to make this thing work, help!!

Answer (score 0):

With windows, configuring the printer is not necessary, but with ubuntu and other linux distributions, it is.  Here is a link from ubuntu.com that shows the process.
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/printing-setup.html.en

Comment: I've tried over and over.  When I get to the page that has the option to test print... the test print button is gray and it is not chickadee. It's searching for drivers but never finds any and eventually freezes up.

Comment: That's really wierd.  You may be missing a package.  Look here for one. https://canondriversupport.net/download-driver-canon-pixma-mg2522-for-windows-mac-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Your printer is likely one of the Canon MG2500 series. See [here](https://canondriversupport.net/download-driver-canon-pixma-mg2522-for-windows-mac-linux/) for Debian packages.